# Restrict previous dates in dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm working on Dialogflow. In my project i have to allow only future dates not previous dates. Can any one know how to achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking about allowing future dates using prebuilt entity `@sys.date`? If yes, answer to your question is No, prebuilt entity here will only help you in identifying dates. If you want to put constraints on this, you will have to write a webhook & explicitly code that way. Webhook is where your actual logic lies so you can directly fetch user entered date in webhook & check if its previous one or future one.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion :-)

Comment: Hi Tejas Bramhecha, do you have any idea on [this](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-cordova-client/issues/38)